# Best way to add a delay in C#

Tags: c#, web-crawler

I am currently building a web crawler and want to add a delay on request so I don't hit web servers to hard.

What is the most appropriate way to add this delay?

Also, what is an appropriate amount of delay for a crawler? I was thinking a .5-1 second.

Thanks

Comment: @CuongLe How is that related to the question? The rules are not absolute, there are questions which don't need any code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
```

Search engines may use larger delays of 10-15 or even 60 seconds. And polite crawlers respect the "Crawl-delay" that site provided in robots.txt. For details, take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Politeness_policy

Comment: Short and sweet. I like it :)